# Cannot communicate with my Kubernetes Cluster using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, yaml

I was trying to get started with AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster provisioning using Terraform. I was following the tutorial and got stuck on the moment with the kubeconfig file.
After the command: `terraform output kubeconfig > ~/.kube/config`, I should be able to communicate with the cluster. Unfortunately, when I try to use any command together with `kubectl`, for example cluster-info, I get an error **error loading config file, yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context**

This is the code of the outputs.tf file:

````
# Outputs
#

locals {
  config_map_aws_auth = <<CONFIGMAPAWSAUTH


apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: ${aws_iam_role.demo-node.arn}
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
CONFIGMAPAWSAUTH

  kubeconfig = <<KUBECONFIG


apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: ${aws_eks_cluster.demo.endpoint}
    certificate-authority-data: ${aws_eks_cluster.demo.certificate_authority[0].data}
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: aws
  name: aws
current-context: aws
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: aws
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      args:
        - "token"
        - "-i"
        - "${var.cluster-name}"
KUBECONFIG
}

output "config_map_aws_auth" {
  value = local.config_map_aws_auth
}

output "kubeconfig" {
  value = local.kubeconfig
}```
````

Comment: You are using heredoc syntax in a wrong way.

Comment: I was following the YouTube tutorial and was repeating everything after the guy. Everything worked in his case. Strange...

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't see the closing line, so my bad.

Comment: What happens when you open the config file in an IDE, does it complain about YML file not being valid?

Comment: It does not allow it to open in IDE

Comment: What does the resulting kubeconfig look like?

Comment: I'll close the question, since I decided to go with Pulumi =)